# Symfony4 FormType: select from entries from other table when adding an item

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a ProductOperatingSystem table/entity and a OperatingSystem table/entity in my symfony4 project.  OperatingSystem has one field 'name' which contain stuff like 'debian', 'windows', etc. productOperatingSystem contains various field plus one field which is a foreign key linked to an operatingSystem entry.

I made a crud for productOperatingSystem  with Symfony and can see all the entries, show or edit one. The issue is when I try to create a productOperatingSystem entry. I got the following error:

> Return value of App\Entity\ProductOperatingSystem::getOperatingSystem() must be an instance of App\Entity\OperatingSystem, null returned

I understand this is because it waits for an object and none is provided, because the way my productOperatingSystem entity is made:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductOperatingSystemRepository")
 */
class ProductOperatingSystem
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $version;


    /**
     * @var OperatingSystem
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\OperatingSystem", inversedBy="productOperatingSystems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $operating_system;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getVersion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $version
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setVersion(?string $version): self
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Operatingsystem
     */
    public function getOperatingSystem(): Operatingsystem
    {
        return $this->operating_system;
    }

    /**
     * @param Operatingsystem $operating_system
     * @return ProductOperatingSystem
     */
    public function setOperatingSystem(Operatingsystem $operating_system): self
    {
        $this->operating_system = $operating_system;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Here is my ProductOperatingSystemType.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\ProductOperatingSystem;
use App\Entity\OperatingSystem;
use App\Repository\OperatingSystemRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class ProductOperatingSystemType extends AbstractType
{
    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('version')
            ->add('is_installed')
            ->add('licence')
        ->add('operating_system');
    ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ProductOperatingSystem::class,
    ]);
    }
}
```

I tried many things but am still lost. What I would like is to be able to select from existing operatingSystem entries when creating a productOperatingSystem item. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use EntityType in your formbuilder for the field 'operating_system'
Like :

```
    $builder
        ->add('version')
        ->add('is_installed')
        ->add('licence')
        ->add('operating_system', EntityType::class, [
           'class' => OperatingSystem::class //your entity class
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My question missed the ProductOperatingSystemController code. It was in there I was able to fix my issue ( @JessGabriel 's answer didn't work ).

Here's the non working code :

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/new/", name="product_operating_system_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $productOperatingSystem = new ProductOperatingSystem();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductOperatingSystemType::class, $productOperatingSystem);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($productOperatingSystem);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('product_operating_system_index');
        }

        return $this->render('product_operating_system/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'productId' => $productId
        ]);
    }
```

The crucial modification was to change:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(ProductOperatingSystemType::class, $productOperatingSystem);
```

with :

```php
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductOperatingSystemType::class);
```